# Oracle xe 18c database shutdowns automatically

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle xe 18 with apex and ORDS successfully on Centos 7, every thing runs fine but after certain inactivity on database like 6/8 hours later Oracle stopped and ORDS throws 503 error code.
Once I start the database up, all are normal then.
Can you please suggest me how to keep Oracle up all time/ unless manually shutdown VPS or the like?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any useful messages in the Alert Log? Or pertinent trace files in the USER_DUMP_DEST directory?

Answer (score 1):

After your database is restarted, connect with an ADMIN level user, and use SQL Developer to inspect the Alert Log - you'll find this as one of the standard reports we ship in the Database Administration section.

[image]

Look for things like 'fatal' 'ora-600' 'abort' - this should clue you in as to what is happening.

We'll assume you don't have a job scheduled on Centos that shuts down the database.

Comment: thanks @thatjeffsmith. My Alert logs from SQL Developer shown only dated of 21-dec-18 instead of today. I started my Oracle database again manually and works fine but knowing that few hours later it will shutdown automatically. And don't have a job scheduled on my Centos VPS to shutdown Database

Comment: keep checking it - there are also physical files on the server you can consult. run this in a sql worksheet to see where 'show parameter BACKGROUND_DUMP_DEST'